# how to eliminate the \N in hive file at hdfs?

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql

I load a data in hive table,some of the columns are empty,while I view the table in hive it shows null.
when I download that data in HDFS in the path /apps/hive/warehouse/dbname/file-name.
In that downloaded file have \N value instead of null.
how to eliminate that \N value with empty in my file.
and also i want to save my file in XLSX format

Comment: Can you show the code, please?

Comment: I answered your first question, please open a new post for the second questions. (Although I suspect you mean to delimited format, e.g. CSV, TSV etc.)

Comment: i ask  a new question in a new post  @dudu Markovitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tblproperties ('serialization.null.format' = '')
```

#### Demo

```
hive> create table t1 (i int,j int,k int);
hive> insert into t1 values (1,null,2);
hive> select * from t1;
```

---

```
+------+------+------+
| t1.i | t1.j | t1.k |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |    2 |
+------+------+------+
```

---

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/t1/* | od -Anone -tacd1x1

    1  soh    \    N  soh    2   nl     # a  = named characters         
    1  001    \    N  001    2   \n     # c  = ASCII characters or backslash escapes
   49    1   92   78    1   50   10     # d1 = decimal     (1-byte)
   31   01   5c   4e   01   32   0a     # x1 = hexadecimal (1-byte)
```

---

```
hive> create table t2 (i int,j int,k int) tblproperties ('serialization.null.format' = '');
hive> insert into t2 values (1,null,2);
hive> select * from t2;
```

---

```
+------+------+------+
| t2.i | t2.j | t2.k |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |    2 |
+------+------+------+
```

---

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/t2/* | od -Anone -tacd1x1

    1  soh  soh    2   nl       # a  = named characters
    1  001  001    2   \n       # c  = ASCII characters or backslash escapes
   49    1    1   50   10       # d1 = decimal     (1-byte)
   31   01   01   32   0a       # x1 = hexadecimal (1-byte)
```